# Why can't I use light theme on non-oled screens when battery saver is on?

Tags: 9.0-pie, themes, dark-mode

This is what I see in display settings when battery saver is on

[image: screenshot]

How does this matter on non-oled screens? I'm using a nokia device

Comment: What device and Android version do you use?

Comment: It seems there's a jump in reasoning between "forced dark theme on Battery Saver" with "cannot use light theme on non-OLED screen". It could be that this enforcement is not global but added by the device manufacturer for other reason, which is why mentioning the device model might be helpful... unless counterproved by providing any existing references to this issue.